# No wifi adapter found , cannot connect Ethernet also

Tags: 18.04, lshw

Unable to connect to Internet via WiFi or Ethernet on Ubuntu 18.04 No network icon. No wifi adapter found. I can however connect WiFi on Windows.

Lshw gives the following output

```
aqid98@aqtd98-VPCEB34EN:-$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for aqid98:
*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Network controller
product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter 
(PCI-Express)
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
version: 01
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHZ
capabilities: pm msi pci express bus v 
master cap list
configuration: latency=0

 resources: memory: f4a00000-f4 off
 *-network UNCLAIMED
 product: AR9285 Wireless Network 
Adapter (PCI-Express)
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
version: 11
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHZ
capabilities: pm msi pci express bus master 
cap list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:f 2220000 f2223fff 
ioport:a000(size=256) 
memory:f 2200000 f221ffff
aqid98@aqid98- VPCEB34EN:~$ Ifconfig
lo: flags 73<UP,LOOPBACK, RUNNING mtu 
65536
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 1 prefixlen 128 scopeid Ox10<host>
loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)
RX packets 985 bytes 72023 (72.0 KB)
RX errorS 0
dropped 0
overruns 0
 frame 0
 TX packets 985 bytes 72023 (72.0 KB)
  TX errors o dropped o overruns O 
carrier 0 collisions 0
```

I had installed kvm and libvirt earlier today for Android studio after which I had a very tough time trying to log into my Ubuntu. Purged Nvidia in recovery shell.

Most answers on the internet assume I can connect either though tethering or Ethernet cabel but both are not working in my case.

Here is the output

```
aqid98@aqid98-VPCEB34EN:-S lspci -knn grep Net -EA3; rfkill 
 list; uname -a
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 
Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. 177H126.00 802.11bgn 
Wireless Half-size Mini PCIE Card [105b:e017
03:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host 
Controller [1180:e822]
Subsystem: Sony Corporation MMC/SD Host Controller 
[104d:9071]
Linux aqid98-VPCEB34EN 4.15.0-58-generic #64 - Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 6 11:12:41 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Corrected command

```
aqid98@aqid98-VPCEB34EN:-5 lspci knn | grep 'EthNet' - EA3; rfkill 
list; uname -a
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 
Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. 177H126.00 802.11bgn 
Wireless Half-size Mint PCIe Card [105b:e017]
03:00.0 SD Host controller [0805): Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host 
Controller [1180:e822]
Subsystem: Sony Corporation MMC/SD Host Controller [104d:9071]
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 
Yukon Optima 88E8059 [PCIe Gigabit Ethernet Controller with AVB][11ab:4381](rev 11)
Subsystem: Sony Corporation Yukon Optima 88E8059 [PCIe Gigabit 
Ethernet Controller with AVB] [104d:9071]
 3f:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c62] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Sony Corporation Core Processor QuickPath 
Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [1040:9071]
3:00.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor 
QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder [8086:2001] (rev 02)
Linux aqid98-VPCEB34EN 4.15.0-58-generic #64 - Ubuntu SMP Tue 
Aug 6 11:12:41 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

aqid98@aqtd98-VPCEB34EN:-$
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep 'Eth|Net -EA3; rfkill list; uname -a` terminal command.

Comment: You don't need sudo. And I changed the command.

Comment: Something is wrong with the kernel. Did you do a fresh install of 18.04, or neteork stopped working after an update?

Comment: Output is wrong, you missed `|`

Comment: The correct command is `lspci -knn | grep 'Eth|Net' -EA3; rfkill list; uname -a`

Comment: I had installed libvirt and kvm today for Android studio which left my Ubuntu in gnome display manager. Purged Nvidia according to few solutions.

Comment: What about `rfkill list`? And it looks like the kernel is not fully installed. There are no modules.

Comment: I suggest to re-install. It wll be easier.

Comment: How do I reinstall without internet? Is there a way to transfer from a working internet connection PC to this?

Comment: You can download an Ubuntu iso, burn it to USB and install the system again. For some unknown reason part of the kernel is not installed. It will be difficult to explain how to install without an internet connection.

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss them.