# Cannot connect to internet via WiFi or Ethernet with a Realtek RTL8822CE

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, ethernet, realtek-wireless

**Please note: before deciding to post here, the resources found at the end of this question were first consulted.**

**Problem:**

WiFi and Ethernet connection are not working. The WiFi and wired connection say they are both connected, however, when trying to access a URL via a browser there is no internet connection (browser messages say the server for any URL cannot be reached). Both wired and WiFi have been tested individually, to no success. It also appears that the PC cannot access the internet via 4G tethering from a mobile connected via USB.

**Details:**

Version: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

The PC was left running from Thursday and over the weekend. On Thursday, the WiFi was working as expected. On the following Monday both WiFi and Ethernet stopped functioning.

**Attempts to diagnose:**

1. Checked for any updates that may have occurred on the Thursday or Friday that may have caused this problem, as seen in the below command and output:

   ```
    $ find /var/lib/dpkg/info/ -name \*.list -mtime -4 | sed 's#.list$##;s#.*/##'
    libgcrypt20:amd64
   ```
2. Pinged `localhost`. This worked completely normally, suggesting the hardware is functioning as it should and this is a software issue.
3. Ran `sudo lspci`. [The output can be seen here](https://pastebin.com/X24T5RgK). It looks like the wireless network adapter can be seen 3rd up from the bottom, so it seems like Ubuntu can find the wireless network card.
4. Ran `sudo lshw -C network`. [The output can be seen here](https://pastebin.com/66RHtW7t) along with details of the wireless/ethernet cards. Again it seems that the system can find the wireless card. Unsure of the relevance of this, but please note
   that on the "configuration" line of the output there is a line that says "firmware=N/A".
5. Ran `sudo lsmod` to see list of modules/drivers. [The output can be seen here.](https://pastebin.com/d50QSQW5)
6. It seems that there is not a name match for the wireless adapter module in the output from `sudo lsmod`, but tried to activate the driver name found in the output from *step (3)* above using `rtw_8822ce` via the following command. Output seen below command.

   ```
    $ sudo modprobe rtw_8822ce
    modprobe: FATAL: Module rtw_8822ce not found in directory /lib/modules/5.11.0-34-generic
   ```
7. Also conducted simple attempts including restarting router and PC multiple times.
8. As suggested in the comments, I have ran `ip route show` which produced the following output:

   ```
    default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600
   ```

**Summary Question:**

- It seems that this problem has arisen over the weekend since an automatic update. Is there any way to re-establish internet connection via WiFi and Ethernet connectivity, despite the fact that Ubuntu is showing that the PC is already connected to the router?

**Resources consulted before posting this question:**

1. https://www.cyberithub.com/solved-no-internet-connection-after-installation-of-ubuntu-20-04/?fbclid=IwAR2TwnGZo2BUApIHEgcbyB_2PM9zZcER0lWcm6-2t-xhvecYaSx_7LNCOV8
2. https://itsfoss.community/t/lost-wi-fi-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04/4682?fbclid=IwAR2TK5RbOQ450RlK9r2JlrC56EyszP62rFZsra2YtKUHOzg4oxCNgPoUPo8
3. https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-wi-fi-not-working-ubuntu/
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800731/module-not-found-when-i-do-a-modprobe?fbclid=IwAR36ezrJ02blDZG_wxSdd5bc7sUxWA7wPqe1OgbiW5letwVWe-SDDo2C_gA
5. [No wifi adapter found , cannot connect Ethernet also](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170275/no-wifi-adapter-found-cannot-connect-ethernet-also)
6. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1652957&fbclid=IwAR0qesFm_mjlYHUz4mK7YCzY988UHI4MemxjLVNnaNWYL-3M8ZXjMx8mbjY
7. [Replace Broadcom "wl" driver with "b43"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149345/replace-broadcom-wl-driver-with-b43/149347?fbclid=IwAR10iRPb_PbZBAf3C3VBSIsyqdW8DyP7KWipuQZQ_nfU3XGIb6gOMXSkkhQ#149347)

---

**Edit:**
There may be a chance that this issue has something to do with the drivers for my wireless network adapter not being compatible with the latest Ubuntu kernel my system has been updated to use. WiFi and ethernet have been working on this same machine for me for the last year.

Comment: Read `man ip ip-route` and look at `ip route show`. The `default` route is where most packets go.

Comment: Thanks, so the output of `ip route show` was: `default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600`. What you please suggest would I can use this information for to have a go at solving this issue?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: @waltinator Okay sure, I have edited the question to include the latest information. Thanks.